# Abort a scheduled job that just sent a batch

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I was wondering what is the best way to remove a scheduled job that just sent a batch.

Sorry but I found no clear answer to this question.

Here is an example :

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    runMyBatch();
    if(someConditions)  System.abort(SC.getTriggerId());
}
```

I guess this way everything is aborted immediatly, and since the batch should run later, it will never run.

Should I send the context as a parameter to the batch then abort from the finish method ?

My purpose is to have a first schedule every day at a specific hour then be able to reschedule every X minutes, depending on a Integer parameter.
The schedule job monitoring should not be invaded by each reschedule.

If you have a better idea, i am interested too ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial answer here :
[Schedulable equivalent of Database.Stateful?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/schedulable-equivalent-of-database-stateful)

Context is to keep the attributes of the schedule instance.

Let's say you have a log inside your schedulable class that you want to keep all day long then email when a specific hour is reached. Or store into a custom setting (you will need an Id to get it back anyway). So you store an attribute.

**Attributes will be saved for next run at the moment you schedule your instance (object is serialized at this moment).**

In the example the job is aborted before it is scheduled again (i was scheduling at the very beginning). It has been tested by users so even if I don't have test it I assume the code is right.

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    changeMyAttribute();
    System.abortJob(sc.getTriggerId());
    schedule();
}
```

Now I am going to work on this. Send the instance to the batch class and run some method in the batch finish method.

Maybe in addition of a nice strategy design pattern (obj 1 don't abort, obj 2 abort, obj 3 send email) ;)

I will give some feedback later.

---

Ok, did some tests and it works great for some time.

**Strategy design pattern :**

Scheduler know 3 kinds of Action objects :

- ActionInit : run batch, don't abort, reschedule
- ActionDefault : run batch, abort, reschedule
- ActionFinish : send email, abort

Action know 2 abstract methods : run(); and finish(); for polymorphism intent. 
And some "toolbox" methods used in child classes.

I change them in the execute() method depending on count (1 = actioninit, >1 = actiondefault, hour>maxHour = actionfinish).

**Where it fails :**

It works well with a very quick run in the middle of the day but fails if I try to run it through the whole day. Without any error message despite try/catches everywhere.

I have a log object that could be too big and send an exception before my try/catches. I am going to clear this.

---

Too bad it seems i can't do:

```
public override String toString(){
    return  ''+
            ' Serialized size:'+JSON.serialize(this).length();
}
```

It is triggering a internal error. Even with .clone(). It would have permit me to check how big the serialized record is ...

---

Ok so here is the working version (for those who could be interested by this kind of problem).

Looks like it was the log object size. It was growing close to 2Mo at the very last working batch. I guess this is a serialization limit.

I did a very compact one with just:

- 1 string for initialization information (parameters, url for callout, etc)
- a list of success and a list of errors with 1 string for each run (depending on batch ending, calculated in finish()

And here is finally how it works :

- execute() from the scheduler chose a object for the strategy design pattern then launch run() polymorphic method.
- it run a batch
- the batch finish methode call the scheduler finish polymorphic methode than add the result, reschedule, send email, whatever
- the scheduler trigger is aborted into the finish() polymorphic method before the reschedule (or not !)

It works very well ! :)

BTW if you are interested by this kind of code, don't hesitate to comment or ask your question.